# How can I evenly space two UIPickerView side by side using storyboard constraints?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uipickerview, xcode-storyboard

Is there a way to evenly space two `UIPickerView` using `storyboard` constraints? I am making an app that has two `UIPickerView` side by side in the same view on landscape mode (I never use portrait mode in this app). So I need to cover all phone sizes.

In iPhone 4 the first `UIPickerView` would go from x=0 to x=240 and the second `UIPickerView` would go from x=240 to x=480. I wish to have the same even spacing like this if the user were to be using a bigger screen resolution (iPhone 5). How can I achieve this? If it is not doable using `storyboard`, how can I do it code? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use a single `UIPickerView` and return 2 in the `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` method on the `UIPickerViewDataSource`?

Comment: I wish at some points to hide the 2nd UIPickerView though. I don't think it is possible to hide a variable amount of components. All or nothing to my knowledge.

Comment: That is possible.. On the `UIPickerView` you can call the `reloadAllComponents` method and return a different amount of components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following constraints shown in Image bellow :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would code (personal preference).

Connect your Storyboard pickers via outlets, then in self.viewDidLoad :

```
// get half the width of the view that holds the pickers
float theWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 2;

// Adjust the firstPicker
self.firstPicker.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,theWidth,self.firstPicker.frame.size.height);

// Adjust the secondPicker
self.secondPicker.frame = CGRectMake (theWidth, 0, theWidth,self.secondPicker.frame.size.height);
```

That would be it - always same size & aligned, half of the view holding it. And you can keep moving things around in your Storyboard for your convenience.

Comment: This doesn't work. Also when I outputted the theWidth value on all phone resolutions it always says 160, so that won't work. The line self.secondPicker.frame = CGRectMake (theWidth, 0, self.secondPicker.frame.size.height); does not have enough arguments (expects 4).

Comment: I forgot to add the width for the secondPicker.frame - obviously. I don't know what you mean by "on all phone resolutions". It works, I'm setting my frames like that day by day, one code for all screen sizes. If you rotate your device, you'll of course want to update the frames. Since I'm adding my pickers in code and not IB, you might have to call the frames in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Ok I must be doing something wrong. Thank you for your help it is nice to know the way to do it in code too :) I accepted the other answer since the question was to do it in storyboard but I really do appreciate your help too.

Comment: No no it's fine - go with what suits your needs best please! I'm not posting to collect points, just want to help. Keep the code in mind for a future with more screen sizes or dynamically changing application window sizes.